# How to write a self-join query in hive for avoiding custom duplicates

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a requirement to get the pair of items by means of the value matched from a table with schema Item, value. I can achieve it by doing a self join but I'm getting duplicate values like depicted below

```
Item     Value
---------------
item1    value1
item2    value1
item3    value3
item4    value2
```

When I do self join with distinct, i get values like

```
Item1    Item2    Value
------------------------
item1    item2    value1
item2    item1    value1
```

But for me, the above rows are duplicate and need only one of them. How can I achieve this? Appreciate your interest and help.

**Note:**
As I have my own definition of duplicated here in this requirement, i referred it as `custom-duplicates` in the question. Please do suggest if they are called by a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple.
Add in the where clause : `Item1>Item2`

Comment: is it that simple? OMG lemme try and get back